# Box plot based on a variable that is not plotted with p values, error bar and percentage reported

Tags: r

```
A <- c("C+P", "S+D", "S+D", "C+P", "C+P", "S+D")
B <- c("WT", "WT", "MUT", "WT", "MUT", "WT")
C <- c("66.67", "33.34", "64.7", "66.6", "35.29", "66.66")
```

Edit: I meant to have this coded as a data frame, which I have hopefully now rectified

```
df <- data.frame("A" = c("C+P", "S+D", "S+D", "C+P", "C+P", "S+D"), "B" = c("WT", "WT", "MUT", "WT", "MUT", "WT"), "C" = c("66.67", "33.34", "64.7", "66.6", "35.29", "66.66"))
```

I would like to create a box plot that depicts the value of C based on A = C+P on the y-axis and the x-axis is two boxes for WT and MUT.

In an ideal world I would like to also have error bars, p value, and above each box the C value reported as (#C+P/total).

So for box B = WT, the y-axis = 66.67 and the value of 50%(2/4) would be displaced above the box plot with error bar.
And for box B = Mut, the y-axis = 35.29 and the value of 50%(1/2) would be displaced above the box plot with error bar.

My code so far, which of course is incomplete and giving me errors of 'computation failed in stat_compare_mean'; error in group_by(A), object "A" not found; geom_errorbar requires min, ymax..."  I don't know how to set the aes(ymin and ymax equations).

```
df %>% group_by(A) 

ggplot(df, aes(x = as.factor(B), y = C, fill = B)) +
theme_bw() + scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1) + geom_bar(stat = "identity",
position = position_dodge()) + 
stat_compare_means(table = "p", method = "t.test", ref.group = "A") +
geom_error_bar()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You do not have any numeric variables. C is a character string. Also `df` is not defined so you cannot pass it to `group_by`.

Comment: Hi dcarlson.  I am sorry I did not format my df correctly.  I think this code is correct for the df. df <- data.frame("A" = c("C+P", "S+D", "S+D", "C+P", "C+P", "S+D"), "B" = c("WT", "WT", "MUT", "WT", "MUT", "WT"), "C" = c("66.67", "33.34", "64.7", "66.6", "35.29", "66.66"))

Comment: You still do not have any numeric data, `df$C` is character. You cannot construct a box plot from character data.

Comment: Would ggplot(df, aes(x = as.factor(B), y = as.numeric(C), fill = B)) solve this issue for you?  I have no problem generating a plot with this piece of code, but truth be told the values in column C were generated from an equation, but for the purpose of this question, that equation was not relevant